# How to use epics, features and pbis

Tags: tfs, agile, scrum, azure-devops

In visual studio online you can already enable Epics, Features, and PBIS

Epics have features and features have PBIs.  We know that in SCRUM PBIs should be completed in a Sprint.

If we have a small project, 2 months, where we decided that Sprints would be 1 week long, then I think it could happen that PBIs and features fit into one sprint, but maybe Epics wont.

Example: 
In an inventory system:

One Epic could be Manage Inventory, but the epic could have 2 features:
1. Manage Products
2. Manage Orders

And the features could have PBIS:
1.1 Add Product
1.2 Delete Product
1.3 Update Product

2.1 Add Order
2.2 Edit order
2.3 Delete Order

If, for example I have an estimated velocity of 80 per Sprint.
And I start estimating effort in all PBIs, lets say at the end of the estimation, if I sum app all efforts of PBIs in feature 1 would give 50, and in the feature 2 would give 60.

Because Feature 1 and Feature 2 are from Epic1. It means I could develop one of the features, but not the entire Epic on the same Sprint.

What would you do in this case? How would you manage this?

Comment: when I check this link http://www.nsilverbullet.net/2013/06/04/features-help-us-plan-work-better-in-team-foundation-service-scrum-process/ it says features are not estimated but VSO has that the effort and iteration field for both Epics and Features

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about project management, not about programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Epic can span several Sprints.

And you can define Features and  PBIs with the Area/Iteration path which is similar to the image below (image is from this msdn [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn798712(v=vs.120).aspx)).

Also have a check of this link for further information on how to use TFS to support epics, release trains, and multiple backlogs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn798712(v=vs.120).aspx
[image]